# Just in time debugger won't install in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, jit

I'm trying to install VS '17, to start programming, and a tutorial told me to install a package. The thing is that this package contains JustInTime. The installation halters when Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime comes up.

So what do I do now?

[image: Visual Studio install stop]

Comment: Do you have AVG antivirus in your machine? If yes, please deactivate it temporarily and run install again. The similar issue on Developer Community:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27352/install-stucks-applying-debuggerjustintime.html   
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15321/visual-studio-2017rc-installer-stuck.html

Comment: @Anders Taje, what about this issue? In addition, the VS2017 has the latest update in march 28, please also update your VS2017 to the latest version, check the result.

Comment: uninstalled AVG still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**
1. Click On Cancel, after few minutes it will ask to update VS installer.
2. Update the Visual Studio Installer. 
3. Restart your PC. Installer will auto-continue.

**Solution 2**
1. Download [Process Explorer](http://filehippo.com/download_process_explorer/)
2. Kill the process PowerShell.exe under vs_installershell.exe
3. Installer will resume skipping JustInTime
4. After VS installation completes you have to manually install JustInTime

**Solution 3**
1. update the System Variable **__PSLockDownPolicy** value to **1**
2. Restart PC
3. Restart installation
[image]

PS: Solution 3 worked for me
REF: [Helpful link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27352/install-stucks-applying-debuggerjustintime.html)

Answer (score 0):

Halts (Freezes)? Or Fails? In my case (failure), it turned out to be a problem with powershell itself. The log the studio installer produces when adding the JIT debugger looks like this:

> The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.
>
> Incomplete components  Just-In-Time debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0)
> You can search for solutions using the information below......be able to find solutions or workarounds.
>
> Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26424.2' failed to install.
>
> Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-65536
>
> Impacted components
> Just-In-Time debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0)
>
> Log
> C:\Users<yourUser>\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup__273_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime.log
>
> Details
> Command executed: "c:\windows\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
> -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command "$ErrorActionPreference="""Stop""";$VerbosePreference="""Continue""";$Action="""Repair""";$AppId="""2763a993""";$Packages="""Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
> ......""";[io.file]::ReadAllText("""C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26424.2\RegisterJustInTimeDebugger.ps1""") | Invoke-Expression; if (!$?) { exit 1603 } elseif ($LastExitCode) { exit $LastExitCode }"
> Return code: -65536
> Return code details: Unknown error (0xffff0000)

If you launch a dos prompt (as admin), run the command listed under "Command executed," and you see this error:

> Internal Windows PowerShell error. Loading managed Windows PowerShell
> failed with error 80070002

You can work around it by opening file explorer to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" and renaming powershell.exe.config. Re-running your powershell command from the dos prompt should now execute without error.